# Probability exercise using geometric distribution—Roulette gambling

Tags: probability, self-study, geometric-distribution

A gambler plays roulette at Monte Carlo and continues gambling, wagering the same amount each time on “Red”, until he wins for the first time. If the probability of “Red” is 18 and the gambler has only 38 enough money for 5 trials.

I need to find the probability that he will win before he exhausts his funds (this means before the 6th trial). The book execute the problem with the inverse probability. Because we need to find $P(X \le 5)$, it is the same as $1 - P(X \ge 6)$, that is $1-(1-P)^5$, with result 0.95. I solved not using the inverse probability, because I can deduce the PDF knowing that it is a geometrical distribution with pdf $f(x) = (20/38)^{x-1}  18/38$. So $P(X\le 5)$ means the summation from $x = 1$ to $x = 5$ of this function result, but it gives me 0.7 ca, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Reference for the problem is: Example 5.12 in Sahoo, Prasanna. (2015). [Probability and Mathematical Statistics.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272237355_Probability_and_Mathematical_Statistics)

Answer (score 3):

You may have made a calculation error -- your approach is correct, and if I compute it in, e.g., R, I find the same result as your book's solution:

```
sum(sapply(1:5,function(x) (20/38)^(x-1) * (18/38)))
```

Output:

```
0.9596139
```